# I have created a cursor using html, css and javascript which is built on this website now the problem is the cursor is moving but not scaling

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor

I have created a cursor using html, css and javascript which is built on [this website](https://redlight.dev/careers/) now the problem is the cursor is moving but not scaling like on this website scale down with cursor movement I want the cursor to move on this website along with scaling down. How can I make it?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const cursor = document.querySelector(".custom-cursor");

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
        const x = e.clientX;
        const y = e.clientY;

        cursor.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`;
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    cursor: none; /* Hide the default cursor */
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.custom-cursor {
    position: fixed;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #ff0000; /* Choose your desired color */
    border-radius: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
    transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="custom-cursor"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: which part of the code you posted would be responsible for "scaling" the cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps? Can be a bit glitchy though

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const cursor = document.querySelector(".custom-cursor");
  let timeout = null;
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    const x = e.clientX;
    const y = e.clientY;

    cursor.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px) scale(0.8)`;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      cursor.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px) scale(1.0)`;
    }, 100);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  cursor: none;
  /* Hide the default cursor */
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.custom-cursor {
  position: fixed;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  /* Choose your desired color */
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-cursor"></div>
```